# converting a string to char *var[]

Tags: c++

try to do something in cpp, I haven't used it in a long time, that requires to parse a string into char *var[]. I cannot seem to figure it out. My current try at it is to use a stringstream and input it that way, but I get a bad **EXC_BAD_ACC**. What I was able to find out about that error is that i'm sending information to somewhere and it cannot do anything with it. What Am I doing wrong and **HOW** should it be done?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#define MAXLINE 80
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *args[MAXLINE/2+1];
    bool ShouldRun = true;
    string hello;
    while(ShouldRun)
    {
        cout << "osh>";
        fflush(stdout);
        cin >> hello;
        int i = 0;

        stringstream ssin(hello);
        while(ssin.good() && 41){
            ssin >> args[i]; //errors here.
            ++i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about `hello.c_str()`? [cppreference.com - c_str](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried that method with strcpy and its says that char* is incompatible with char**. it even tried strcpy((char*)args,hello.c_str()); but that gives me bad access too.

Comment: `char *args[MAXLINE/2+1];` declares and *array-of-pointers* `[MAXLINE/2+1]` of them, not a character *array*. Declare `char args[MAXLINE/2+1];` (no `'*'`)

Comment: You're making the mistake of thinking a pointer is an array.   It is not.   `args` is an array of uninitialised pointers.   Each `args[i]` (a pointer) needs to be initialised to point at (the first character of) an array of characters, BEFORE doing `ssin >> args[i]`.   Each array needs to have enough elements to hold whatever will be written to it.    Better yet, rather than mixing C code with C++, use `std::string` from the C++ standard header `<string>` - make `args` an array of `std::string` (since `std::string` will implicitly manage the array it contains).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I tried that method with strcpy and its says that `char*` is incompatible with `char**`"*

That error is telling. In your code you declare `args` as:

```
char *args[MAXLINE/2+1];
```

That does not declare a *character array*, that declares *an array of pointers to* `char`, `MAXLINE/2+1` of them.

Now your code is a bit ambiguous whether you want a simple c-string or whether you want an array of them. Given `#define MAXLINE 80`, and your check against `41` it appears you simply want a c-string and not an array of c-strings. In that case, you simply need to change your declaration to:

```
char args[MAXLINE/2+1];
```

That creates an *array of* `char` of 41-bytes which has storage for maximum of 40-characters (plus the *nul-terminating character*). To convert `hello` to a c-string, you need only use the `.c_str()` member function. (see  [cppreference.com - c_str](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str)) You need to validate it will fit first which you can do with `hello.length()`.

Putting it together, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

#define MAXLINE 80

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    char args[MAXLINE/2+1];     /* array of char - not pointers */
    bool ShouldRun = true;
    string hello;

    while(ShouldRun)
    {
        cout << "osh> ";
        if (!(cin >> hello))
            break;

        if (hello.length() <= MAXLINE/2) {  /* validate length of hello */
            strcpy (args, hello.c_str());       /* copy to args */
            cout << "args: " << args << '\n';   /* output args */
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/string2c_str
osh> first_arg
args: first_arg
osh> second_arg
args: second_arg
osh>
```

If you want to store all inputs as separate c-strings within an array of pointers, then you will either need to allocate storage and assign the starting address to each `args[i]` before copying to it, or declare `args` as a 2D-array of fixed size. Let me know if that is what you are attempting.

**Using an Array of Pointers to Char**

To use `execvp` as indicated in your comment, then `args` does indeed need to a *an array of pointers to* `char` where the next pointer after your last argument must be explicitly set `NULL` to indicate end-of-arguments.

You also must insure you fill no more than `MAXLINE/2` pointers leaving the last explicitly set `NULL`. You can set all pointers `NULL` by initialization and then you allocate `hello.length() + 1` characters of storage for each string, assigning the beginning address of the new block to `args[i]` before copying the c-string to that address.

Putting this example together, you would have:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

#define MAXLINE 80

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    char *args[MAXLINE/2+1] = {nullptr};    /* array of pointers to char */
    bool ShouldRun = true;
    int n = 0;
    string hello;

    while(ShouldRun)
    {
        cout << "osh> ";
        if (n == MAXLINE/2 || !(cin >> hello)) {    /* protect bounds */
            cout << '\n';
            break;
        }

        args[n] = new char [hello.length() + 1];    /* allocate storage */
        strcpy (args[n++], hello.c_str());          /* copy to args[n] */
    }

    n = 0;
    while (args[n]) {           /* output args until NULL encountered */
        cout << "args[" << n << "]: " << args[n] << '\n';
        delete[] args[n++];     /* don't forget to free what you allocate */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the arguments are stored until the read-loop exits by generating a manual `EOF` with <kbd>Ctrl+c</kbd> on Linux (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd>) on windows))

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/string2c_str_array
osh> arg_1
osh> arg_2
osh> arg_3
osh>
args[0]: arg_1
args[1]: arg_2
args[2]: arg_3
```

Comment: ultimately i need the args to work with this... execvp(char *command, char *params[]);

Comment: OK, you do need an array of pointers with the pointer after your final argument set explicitly `NULL`. Hold on and I'll add an answer.